# Splicing arbitrary expressions in a Haskell quasiquoter

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Reading through [Why It’s Nice to be Quoted](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mainland/publications/mainland07quasiquoting.pdf), in section 3 there's an example of splicing a variable identifier in a quasiquote.

```
subst [:lam | $exp:e1 $exp:e2 |] x y =
    let e1' = subst e1 x y
        e2' = subst e2 x y
    in
        [:lam | $exp:e1' $exp:e2' |]
```

I see why the recursive calls to `subst` are done outside the `[:lam| ... |]`, it's because the function `antiVarE` in section 3.2 builds a `TH.varE` out of the variable name.

My question is how much work would be required to support arbitrary expression splices beyond just a variable name?

For example:

```
subst [:lam | $exp:e1 $exp:e2 |] x y =
      [:lam | $exp:(subst e1 x y) $exp:(subst e2 x y) |]
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for posterity.

Turns out it was quite simple.  Using the `parseExp` function in [haskell-src-meta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta) package I was able to easily convert a string to AST fragment.

In the original paper, aside from the parser changes required to capture an expression string between parentheses, the `antiExpE` function could be rewritten as such.

```
antiExpE :: Exp -> Maybe TH.ExpQ
antiExpE (AE v) =
    case parseExp v of
        Right exp -> Just . return $ exp
        Left _    -> Nothing
antiExpE = Nothing
```