# How to allow embedding not only values but arbitrary haskell expressions in antiquotes

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, quotations

Recently, I have learned how to implement quasiquoters with antiquote capabilities, like `printfQ` in the following piece of code:

```
main = do
  let itemName = "apple"
      price = 1.29 
  [printfQ| The price of #{itemName} is #{price}. |]
```

The ingredient string of the quasiquote will be passed to `quoteExp printfQ :: String -> ExpQ`. So what we do is to parse the given `String`, find names to be embedded `"itemName"` and `"price"`, apply `varE . mkName` for each name, and build the `ExpQ`.

Now suppose I'd like to extend this `printfQ` to allow expression embedding as follows:

`[printfQ| The price of #{itemNames !! i} is #{price + taxOf price}. |]`

I can write the parser that detects two string`"itemNames !! i"` and `"price + taxOf price"`. But then I need a stronger version of `varE . mkName`, a function of type `String -> ExpQ` that turns those strings into `ExpQ`, interpreting them as expressions referring to the namespace the `printfQ` is used.

**My question:** is there any library function that does this string to AST conversion? Are there some easy ways to do this, or do I need to write an entire Haskell parser?

- This question is closely related to this question [Is there a template haskell function for quoting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662862/is-there-a-template-haskell-function-for-quoting)  I'm posting this in hope that stating the question in more focused and clearer way may assist the community to find an answer.

Comment: I asked the same question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541899/splicing-arbitrary-expressions-in-a-haskell-quasiquoter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After taking a bath an excellent idea came to me:

> Hey, if I need an entire Haskell parser, why not use an existing one?

After a couple of search in that line I found my answer: `parseExp` from 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.4/docs/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html#v:parseExp .

I wrote a self-contained example for this:

https://github.com/nushio3/practice/tree/master/template-haskell/embed-expr